# Python script to find files that contain specific multiple strings (that aren't guaranteed to be in order)

Tags: python

I would like to find files in a given folder that contain specific given strings. For example:

I have a folder "Students" that contains files with students' info (first names, last names and their home city, their GPA, etc. **that are not in order**) - something like:

```
student1.txt | student2.txt | student3.txt | student4.txt | student5.txt | student6.txt
John         | Kim          | Barnes       | Steven       | 2.0          | Terry
Barnes       | Pen          | John         | Horns        | Barnes       | McGinnis
Detroit      | Gotham       | Detroit      | Chicago      | Detroit      | Gotham
4.0          | 2.4          | 3.5          | 2.6          | John         | 2.8
```

As you can see, in our theoretical situation here we have students 1, 3 and 5 all have the same first name, last name, and city, but they have different GPA.

So I would like to ask how I can input "John", "Barnes", "Detroit", and get the output as names of the files that contains the same 3 required strings:

```
student1
student3
student5
```

So far, I have (OS module used to find path to the folder):

```
import os

# The path is taken care of - I don't want to waste space here
for filename in os.listdir(path):

   fname = input("Enter first name: ")
   lname = input("Enter last name: ")
   city = input("Enter home city: ")

   line = file.readline()
   line_num = 1

   while line != '':
      #search for strings' indexes
      fn_index = line.find(fname)
      ln_index = line.find(lname)
      city_index = line.find(lname)
   
      if(index != -1)
         # I don't know what to do here 

         # My desired output (filename was taken care of)
         print(filename, fname, lname, homecity)

      line_num += 1

   file.close()
```

Please note that fname, lname, city and GPA **are not in order**. The above is just an example.

That's all. If my question is already answered, please let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: ```file.readlines()```, ``````filename.readlines()``````

Comment: Thank you. Let say those lines aren't in order, is there a way around?

Comment: `first names, last names and their home city, their GPA, etc. that are not in order` Could you please elaborate this? It's not a normal requirement, we can't handle such kinds of formats, the input file content should be unified.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin yes, so chances are the files may contain the specific strings, but it's not guaranteed that those strings are in order. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, where did you get such data? May refer : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_wrangling

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I see. What if we do something like check if those 3 exists in the file? Like if (str1 is in file) && (str2 is in file) && (str3 is in file) print the file.

Comment: @HumbleHermit What if some person A's first name is equal to B's last name, and A's last equal to B's first name? You can check with string contains, but it's not accurate.

Comment: I'm sorry, the students are just an example. My bad - I used a too specific example. 
My situation is that I have many files, and I want to find the files that contain specific strings. Like 5 files with hundreds of names, but only 3 of them contain all the names John, Tom, Charlie (we don't care about the order). I should have used this example...

Answer (score 1):

It's a straightforward task, we read all files one by one, and match the desired part(first name, last name, and city)

To skip unwanted files, we use regex to match the input file names with the pattern: student + $id + txt suffix

To print get the result with format `student1` we just remove the suffix

```py
import re
import os
fname_desire = input("Enter first name: ")
lname_desire = input("Enter last name: ")
city_desire = input("Enter home city: ")

# The path is taken care of - I don't want to waste space here
path="."
pat = "student\d+.txt"
prog = re.compile(pat)
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not prog.match(filename):
        continue

    with open(filename) as cin:
        fname= cin.readline().rstrip('\n')
        lname = cin.readline().rstrip('\n')
        city = cin.readline().rstrip('\n')

        if fname == fname_desire and lname == lname_desire and city == city_desire:
             # My desired output (filename was taken care of)
             print(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the order, check it as a list

```
import os

path = r"Your PATH"

fname = input("Enter first name: ")
lname = input("Enter last name: ")
city = input("Enter home city: ")

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename)) as file:
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file.readlines()]
        if ((fname in lines) and (lname in lines) and (city in lines)):
            # Desired output (filename was taken care of)
            print(filename, fname, lname, city)
        file.close()
```